# Excel 2010 Relative Link to Cells in other Workbooks

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make relative links in excel to other excel files within cells. When the files are within same folder all the links are okay, but when the file is in the parent folder than links becoming a problem when moving the files.

I'm trying to do something like ..\Workbook.xlsm to look for the file in the parent folder, but for some reason I cannot find any solution to this except for VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be possible but care is needed when managing links between folders. Check this MS knowledgebase article for details of how Excel manages links: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328440.

Unzipping the contents of the .xlsm file allows the paths of the link locations to be checked if required.